# Tag inheritance respecting mutual exclusivity in org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

Is it possible to have tag inheritance respect mutually exclusive tag groups in org-mode? What I would like to do is set a default tag on a top-level entry, and override it with one of the other tags in a mutually exclusive group on some children in the tree. My expectation is that the child tag would override the ancestor because they are mutually exclusive. But currently this doesn't work as the child will have both the ancestor tag and its own, even though they should be mutually exclusive.

Comment: did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: This would be very useful where the upper-level is the final step following the steps of its children (or it simply holds default tags for its children) and you use GTD-style context tags. E.g. you would like to "uninherit" `@home` if the context of the inheriting entry is `@errands`, just as the two would not appear together in the same entry.

Comment: I haven't found an answer to this yet.

Comment: I think a better way to solve this is by using properties.